# How can I create the Route in Kohana 3.2 for this directory structure: /application/my_use_case/classes/

Tags: kohana, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create the Route in Kohana 3.2 for this directory structure: /application/my_use_case/classes/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075558/how-can-i-create-the-route-in-kohana-3-2-for-this-directory-structure-applicat)

I'm using Kohana 3.2 and I need to create this directory structure for my application:

```
     /application/my_use_case_1/classes/controller/..
     /application/my_use_case_1/classes/model/..
     /application/my_use_case_2/classes/controller/..
     /application/my_use_case_2/classes/model/..
```

What's the Route that I need to create to have this structure ?

Thanks.

Cheers,
Luiz

Answer (score 1):

Simply put - there isn't one. You can either have separate applications in separate folders or have application/classes/directory routes:

```
<?php
Route::set('global', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>))', 'directory' => 'app1|app2|app3')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'app1',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

so the class names will look like `App1_Controller_Index` and file structure like `app1/controller/index.php`

Comment: Hi Kemo, I'm using your Route, but I'm doing something wrong yet.

So, this is my directory structure for "Settings" use case:

       - ..\application\settings\classes\controller\settings.php
       - ..\application\settings\classes\model\settings.php


And this is the code for my controller:

        class Controller_Settings extends Controller {
       
           public function action_index(){
               echo 'test';
           }
       }

And this is the url that I'm using to access my controller:
       - http://cmx107/clients/cmcaapp/v1/settings