# How can I create the Route in Kohana 3.2 for this directory structure: /application/my_use_case/classes/

Tags: controller, kohana, routes

I'm using Kohana 3.2 and I need to create the directory structure below for my application. For that, I'm using the Route below, but I'm doing something wrong yet. "Settings" is my use case that I'm developing.

```
<?php
Route::set('global', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>))', array('directory' => 'settings'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'settings',
        'controller' => 'settings',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
?>
```

So, this is my directory structure for "Settings" use case:

```
   - ..\application\settings\classes\controller\settings.php
   - ..\application\settings\classes\model\settings.php
   - ..\application\settings\views\settings_form.php
```

And this is the code for my controller:

```
   class Controller_Settings extends Controller {

       public function action_index(){
           echo 'test';
       }
   }
```

And this is the url that I'm using to access my controller:

```
   - http://cmx107/clients/cmcaapp/v1/settings
```

Thanks,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since you set directory to default to settings, you need to put your controller Settings in the Settings directory like this rather than the way you did it:

**Paths**

Correct: application/classes/settings/settings.php

Format: apppath/classes/<directory>/<controller>.php

```
Class Controller_Settings_Settings extends Controller {
    public function action_index(){
       echo 'test';
   }
}
```